# Is it possible to go back to line after error in PL/SQL? 

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have tons of insert statements.

I want to ignore errors during the execution of these lines, and I prefer not to wrap each line seperately.

Example:

```
try
    insert 1
    insert 2
    insert 3
exception
    ...
```

I want that if an exception was thrown in insert 1, it will ignore it and go back to perform insert 2, and etc.

How can I do it?

I'm looking for something like "Resume next" in VB.

Comment: Do you have to use PLSQL ? Can't you run these inserts from sql*plus ?

Comment: I can, But I have to let it run even if an erlier statement failed.

Comment: I mean running it a script and not as an anonymous block. if you can then every statment will run by its own

Comment: Check [Continuing Inserts in Oracle when exception is raised](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065829) for an answer about DML Error logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can move all the inserts to a sql script and then run them in sql*plus, then every insert will run by its own and the script will continue to run.

If you are using plsqldeveloper (you taged it), then open a new command window (wich is exactly like a sql script run by sql*plus) and put your staements like this:

```
insert into table your_table values(1,'aa');
insert into table your_table values(2/0,'bb');
insert into table your_table values(3,'cc');
commit;
```

Even though statement (2) will throw an execption, since it's not in a block it will continue to the next command.

**UPDATE:** According to @CheranShunmugavel comment, add

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE NONE
```

at the top of the script (especially if your using sql*plus which there the difault is `exit`).

Comment: To be safe, you may want to add the line `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE NONE` at the top of your script ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm#i2700066)), in case the default behavior is different.  (According to the doc, the default behavior is to exit)

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to wrap each `INSERT` statement with its own exception handler.  If you have "tons" of insert statements where any of the statements can fail, however, I would tend to suspect that you're approaching the problem incorrectly.  Where are these statements coming from?  Could you pull the data directly from that source system?  Could you execute the statements in a loop rather than listing each one?  Could you load the data first into a set of staging tables that will ensure that all the `INSERT` statements succeed (i.e. no constraints, all columns defined as VARCHAR2(4000), etc.) and then write a single SQL statement that moves the data into the actual destination table with appropriate validations and exception handling?

Comment: I'm trying to add "hard coded" values to the tables. But, because there is a possibility that part of the script run before, a constraint can fail some of the statements...

Comment: Agreed - upload to staging tables, and trap for errors on true insert to tables.  Use multiple sets of tables if necessary.

Comment: @MattanLevy - Could you delete the hard-coded rows and then re-insert them?  Could you write `MERGE` statements rather than `INSERT` statements?  Could you load the hard-coded values into a staging table and then write a single `INSERT` to load the data from the staging table into your production table?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [log error clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH). More information in [Avoiding Bulk INSERT Failures with DML Error Logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables004.htm#InsertDMLErrorLogging)