# PL/SQL Dynamic Table Names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm pretty new to Oracle so not entirely sure this is possible, or if perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way but here goes ...

Part of an old feeder script I'm fixing is looping through ~ 20 tables (could change anytime) to populate relevant staging tables. This part is currently *very* basic:

```
...

INSERT INTO staging_tbl_1(
     SELECT *
     FROM source_tbl_1    
);

INSERT INTO staging_tbl_2(
         SELECT *
         FROM source_tbl_2    
);

...
```

Some of the fields in the source database have different constraints etc which means that every now and then it will throw an exception and the feeder will stop. What I'm hoping to do is create a procedure within the existing feeder package to loop through each row in each record before it is inserted and simply wrap it in an exception block. This way it can be logged without causing the feeder to stop.

Essentially I'm chasing something like this:

```
BEGIN procedure_x(source_record, staging_record)

  -- Perform validation to ensure records exit

  -- Loop through all record rows
  FOR row IN (SELECT * FROM source_record) LOOP

     -- Wrap in exception block

     -- Insert into staging record

     -- Log exception if it occurs
  END LOOP;         
END
```

I've attempted ref cursors however in order to get them to work I would also need to know the rowtype in advance (from my limited understanding). I've also tried execute immediate however I cannot find a way to loop this in an appropriate way. Are there any other ways to tackle this?

**Additional:**

I realise that we really should be fixing the source of the problem rather than going about it like this, unfortunately it is far outside my area of influence.

It is possible to do this without making a separate procedure and just wrap all of the table references in a loop, however I'd like to leave this as a last resort.

Comment: Did you try `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and `BULK COLLECT` the records into an associative array which you can then loop through? That might solve your looping issue.

Comment: Hey Ollie, thanks for the reply - unfortunately, if my understanding of bulk collect is correct, I would still have to know what the rowtype is before executing it. I'm currently looking into dbms_sql and creating a procedure to dynamically create all of this via all_tables etc. However, this is pretty messy for such a small fix -  if anyone has another idea please let me know :)

Comment: you can wrap an anon. block around the insert statement within the for loop - take a look at my previous question [Continuing Inserts in Oracle when exception is raised](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065829)

Comment: Thanks for the input Sathya, unfortunately I don't think this addresses the issue of needing to know the name of the record beforehand to create the for loop (the execute immediate problem etc). At this stage it looks like the DML error logging mentioned by Adam is probably my best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has functionality for logging of DML errors. Use it with single SQL statements. Don't go row-by-row and make your processes crawl.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN10261

Comment: Thanks Adam, I think this is what I'm probably going to have to use. Not quite the way I was hoping to go about it, but as you say it is far more efficient.